# Divide lines and save on array

Tags: java

I have a string like this:

```
hello hello hello hello
hi hi hi hi hi hi
bye bye bye bye bye
```

I am using java and I want to save on array each line, how can I do this?

Comment: Provide sample output, i.e. what you are trying to achieve

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean. You've got a string which is already covering three lines... what's the array? What do you mean by "save on array each line"? Do you mean you want a string array with one element per line? If so, what are your line breaks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's try following code:

```
String lines="hello hello hello hello"
                 +"hi hi hi hi hi hi"
                 +"bye bye bye bye bye";
    String test[]={lines.substring(0,lines.indexOf("hi")),lines.substring(lines.indexOf("hi"),lines.indexOf("bye")),lines.substring(lines.indexOf("bye"))};
    List<String> list=Arrays.asList(test);
    System.out.println(list);
```

**Output :**

```
[hello hello hello , hi hi hi hi hi , bye bye bye bye bye]
```

**Note:** I would suggest you to use `substring` rather than `split` if lines are on the same line.

If the lines are actually on next line try following:

```
List<String> list=Arrays.asList(lines.split("\\n"));
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.split("\n")` where `\n` should `split` your `String` by lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
String lines[] = String.split("\\r?\\n");
```